# Promise.race fires "timeout is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

This is my code of a react native application with a login form to dispatch an API call. The event handler of the login button will dispatch the apiLogin-Action:

```
    try {
      await Promise.race([
          dispatch(actions.doApiLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)),
        timeout(15000),
      ]);
    } catch (e) {
      const message = e.message || e;
      if (message !== 'Timed out' && message !== 'Canceled by user') {
        alert(message);
        console.warn(e);
      }
      return;
    } finally {
      this._isMounted && this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }
```

It throws an exception "timeout is not defined". This code is taken from Facebooks [F8-Application](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/LoginButton.js#L83). I couldn't find details about Promise.race-Method, which are handled this way on the internet, but facebook runs an app with that...

What is wrong with passing the timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Promise.race`, perhaps you forgot to define the function `timeout`, this is how the function is defined in the [source code](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/LoginButton.js#L102-L106)

```
async function timeout(ms: number): Promise {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timed out')), ms);
  });
}
```

As you can see it's a simple promise that is rejected when ms millisecond have elapsed, `Promise.race` is resolved/rejected with the first promise that is resolved/rejected